# $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $S_n$ is the set of points $p$ with equal distance to the origin as their minimum distance from any point in $S_{n-1}$

Tags: geometry

Let $S_0 = \{(1,0)\}$.
For all positive integers $n$, $S_n$ is the set of points $p$ with equal distance to the origin as their minimum distance from any point in $S_{n-1}$
We need to find the area enclosed by $S_3$

I think it's $\frac{19}{144}$ the euclidean metric version ends up being $\frac{9\sqrt3}{40}$
length of those 2 is also probably pretty fun to calculate
i wonder if there is a general formula for $S_n$ area with the Manhattan or maybe Chebyshev.

Comment: What is the 19/144 supposed to be?

Comment: @user10354138 manhattan metric

Comment: as you can guess from the question, i think it’s a jordan curve